# Agrupar en Tabla Jquery

Tags: jquery

Me gustaría saber de que forma puedo agrupar por modelo ademas de obtener la suma de cantidades y costo de los datos agrupados. 
Busco esta solución en particular debido a que son datos que ingresa el usuario y este necesita visualizar un resumen de su pedido, no puedo obtener estos datos de ninguna consulta a la bd.

A continuación un ejemplo :

```
<table id="tabla_vehiculos" class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Marca</th>
              <th>Modelo</th>
              <th>costo</th>
              <th>cantidad</th>
               <th>color</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Audi</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>azul</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Audi</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>rojo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Audi</td>
            <td>A4</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>verde</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Audi</td>
            <td>A4</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>rojo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>suzuki</td>
            <td>swift</td>
            <td>250</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>amarillo</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

El resultado que busco seria algo como esto:

> Audi A3 4 $400, 
>   Audi A4 3 $600,
>   suzuki swift 2 $500

Intente hacerlo con un each de jquery a la tabla usando validaciones pero me di cuenta que de esta forma no podría  resolverlo, quedo atento a sus respuestas saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var arrayVehiculos = {};
        $('#tabla_vehiculos tbody tr').each(function(){
        var index = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text() + $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
        var costo = parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(2).text());
        var cantidad = parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(3).text());
        if(typeof arrayVehiculos[index] === 'undefined'){
          arrayVehiculos[index] = {
            'marca' : $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(),
            'modelo' : $(this).find('td').eq(1).text(),
            'costo' : 0,
            'cantidad' : 0
          }
        }
        arrayVehiculos[index] = {
          'marca' : $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(),
          'modelo' : $(this).find('td').eq(1).text(),
            'costo' : arrayVehiculos[index].costo + costo,
            'cantidad' : arrayVehiculos[index].cantidad + cantidad
        };

        });

        console.log(arrayVehiculos);

        $.each(arrayVehiculos, function(index,value){

            $('#resultado').append(value.marca + ' ' + value.modelo + ' ' + value.costo + ' ' + value.cantidad + '<br/>');
        });
```

Y tendrías que agregar:

```
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

En el siguiente fiddle está implementado: https://jsfiddle.net/2xLa1guw/

Espero haber entendido bien el problema esta vez, dime si tienes alguna duda.

Comment: Estimado , revise tu código pero lo que necesito es agrupar no ordenar, saludos gracias por darte el tiempo de responder

Comment: Edité mi respuesta, disculpa no leí bien tú enunciado. Espero te sirva esta vez.

Comment: gracias me sirvió mucho.